# Google does not find canonical URL on indexed page even though it finds it in a live test

Tags: google-search-console, rel-canonical

I have a problem where Google ignores my set canonical tag.

If I use the "URL inspection" tool in the new Google search console I can see that on the indexed page they could not find any "**User-declared canonical**".

But when I run the Live test they can. Please see the attached images.

Any ideas why this is the case?

This is the link I've tested:

`http://newsroom.notified.com/news/25152/swiss-clinic-skin-roller---best-diy-buy-at-th`

[image: Google Indexed page]

[image: Google Live test page]

Comment: Try to remove id="canonical-url" and place the link rel canonical at the beginning of the header section.